# How to exclude one fading-direction of Fresnel material?

Tags: 3d, render, hlsl, unreal-engine5

The Fresnel outline is constituted by both 'face-inwardness' and 'face-slideness' . Imagine a sphere , that it has outer faces inwards so dot(incoming_ray , surface_normal) -> 0 . And , imagine a plane , that it has its center focused by your eye and the surrounding faces 'slide' away from your most concentrated awareness , like a spot light, that is , having the central perpendicular sight ( normal overlaps incoming-ray) slide towards parallel angle , and dot(incoming_ray , surface_normal) changes from 1 to nearly 0.

Basically , what I'd tried are...

1.Establishing Incoming-ray space . In UE5 , you can express it by 'Object Position - Camera Position' (Nodes) . That is , finding out from where our object is facing towards us -- from what angle and what distance , and expressing it in a vector3 . You can understand it as the player plays a role of a point light , emitting rays on the surfaces of everything around it . You can call it as 'view direction' as well .

2.Eliminating rays' altitudinal location info . (Because the previously gotten vector is normalized , Z info affects X and Y's lengths , we must normalize the without-height vector to entirely clear the height-influence).

3.Calculate dot(incoming-ray,surface-normal) .

It works fine , when you put it standing still . However , my problem is that , the Z-Elimination is fixed and when I put it down (rotate it) , the eliminated-area would not be changed , and the object's tip fell into un-eliminated area , and black shadows belonging to the un-eliminated X and Y areas devoured it .

That's not a true Fresnel Material excluding one axis .

```
    //VS
    float4x4 worldMatrix = ComputeWorldMatrix(......);

    Struct vertex = (Struct)0;

    vertex.normal = normalize(mul(normal, (float3x3)worldMatrix)); //world space normal
    vertex.position = mul(vertex.position, worldMatrix); //world space vertex

    vertex.position = mul(vertex.position, viewMatrix);//transform to view space
    vertex.viewDirection = mul((float3x3)viewMatrix, normalize(vertex.position.xyz));//incoming-ray space
    vertex.viewDirection.y = 0;
    vertex.viewDirection = normalize(vertex.viewDirection);

    ....
    //PS

    float output = saturate(abs(dot(vertex.viewDirection, vertex.normal)));
    output = pow(output , 1.8);
```

[Expected Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYLWZ.png)
[When you put it down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emb46.png)

I've tried to ignore rotation transform in worldMatrix and the result was , the Fresnel color got fixed to the model , and when I rotated it around height axis , the blackness which should be at the side flipped out and let me saw it , like what Local Position node does in UE5 .

My another solution is putting inverse(ViewMatrix) rotation transform in worldMatrix and replace the object's vanilla world rotation transform . But I don't know how to do that .